# C++ is delete operator rewrite memory?

Tags: c++, memory

I'm working on a project using `MVS 2010 C++`. Compile options are default. I thought that operator `delete` didn't rewrite memory and only marks memory that is free in the heap. I did a test project where a string is created dynamically by the `new` operator and deallocated by the `delete` operator. I  examined the memory in the memory window and after the `delete` the memory was overwritten. It's happening in release too. In release mode (without debug) I created a dump of the process and searched for the string in notepad. I found the string. Then I created a dump after the `delete` and searched for the string in the dump file. The string was not there.

My question is why does `delete` overwrite the string even in release mode?

Comment: provide a [minimal, verifiable example code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please

Comment: If I understood your problem : You can't find your string in a dump file after you `delete`d it after allocating memory? Then that's normal, because it was deallocated, and no longer part of your program memory.

Comment: If you free a piece of memory by calling delete, anyone can write to it after that. Depending on your OS and the place where the block was allocated, this can be a totally different program or even the OS itself.

Comment: please remember to accept an answer if it answered your question

Answer (score 1):

In many popular implementation of heap management "marking memory that is free in the heap" does usually entail rewriting at least part of that memory. That's how it is "marked as free".

Typically some portion of the now-free memory block is actually used for internal purposes by the heap manager (maintaining free block list etc.) This re-purposing and subsequent rewriting is most likely what you observe in your case.

Usually it is the very beginning of the free block that gets reused for internal purposes. In some implementations it might be the beginning and the end. So, if you allocate a string that is long enough, you should be able to see at least the central portion of that string lingering intact in the freed memory block.

Don't make it too long though, since heap manager might decide to request large memory blocks directly from the OS and return them back to the OS once they are freed. And that's a wholly different story.

Answer (score 0):

With old C, you could free a block and it would remain valid until the next call to malloc(). But that hasn't been true for a long time now. Applications often "shred" memory, partly to assist debugging, but also as a security measure to prevent other code looking through the garbage, maybe to hoover up passwords or other sensitive information. Also the memory could have been given to another process.

Answer (score 0):

Once you invoke delete the memory manager is free to do anything it wants with the memory. Any number of things could be happening, including:

1. It could overwriting for debugging purposes
2. Adding the block to the free memory pool
3. Merging freed blocks.
4. The block is reallocated and written somewhere else (e.g. in a library function).

It is unrealistic for you to have any expectation that your data will not be overwritten when you delete.